# How to create n number of rules dynamically using @function?

Tags: sass

My question is really simple. How can we create rules inside a function. For example we want to create 5 classes for font-size. We will do like

```
@for $i from 0 through 4{
   .size#{$i}{
      font-size:($i * 10)
   }
}
```

But what if we want to do that using a function. Actually I want to do that the same for other properties as I did for `font-size`. So I create a function which will receive some data and then create rulesets.But problem is that I can't use rulesets inside function.

```
@function createRuleSets(){
   @for $i from 0 through 4{
      .size#{$i}{
         font-size:($i * 10)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You cannot with `@function` (functions returns values, not definitions), but you can with `@mixin`. Then just use `@include createRuleSets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `@mixin` instead of a `@function`:

```
@mixin createRuleSets( $base: 1px ){
   @for $i from 0 through 4{
      .size#{$i}{
         font-size:($base * $i * 10)
      }
   }
}

@include createRuleSets( 20px );
```

Functions return values, not rulesets. Mixins allow you to mix in rulesets. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

(I added an argument to the mixin to show how they actually work almost exactly like functions, except for rulesets.)